# Error Updating My Character to Mixamo

Tags: animation, bones, mixamo

I made and rigged a character in Blender and when I imported it to Mixamo.

It said 'Error while generating motion'

Here's the file:

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1_3DFufVQkxMRXcEDNc6dAo2ewLJ5rNfS

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello user161250: Please avoid using ALL CAPS.... it's considered shouting, and a bit rude. Insofar as this _is_ a Blender problem, we may be able to help you. Please give us the export format, and any other details that may help us help you. Your file-link is private, and inaccessible. Please use https://blend-exchange.com/, and follow the instructions there. If it's a Mixamo problem. not a Blender problem, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Is there a *Mirror* modifier on the mesh? The character's center line looks strange in Mixamo.